# Hazelcast : Can I access IMap from Memcached?

Tags: java, memcached, hazelcast, spymemcached

How can I get an `IMap` or whatever instance created in `Hazelcast Server` side from the `Memcached Client`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hazelcast has a native Memcached protocol client

http://hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/hazelcast-documentation.html#memcache-client

Answer (score 1):

Just create a memcached client and connect it to the Hazelcast memcached server. It should work as you would expect it from a native memcached server.

Any problem or just not yet tried?